# Как распарсить строку функции php http_build_query()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Php функция [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php) генерирует URL-кодированную строку запроса (по умолчанию, PHP_QUERY_RFC1738). Как на стороне js эту строку распарсить, чтобы получить доступ к значениям? Пример данных, которые получают от сервера в переменную

```
person_id=120&laboratory_prefix_id=5&sample_number=155&total_cost=0.00&receiving_date=2017-08-18&barcode=12-55fff&country_id=20&sample_priority=2&sample_note=sdfsdfsdf&sample_id=15&laboratory_id=1&prefix_id=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getParameterByName(name,string) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(string);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Работает. Как выйдет таймер, отмечу вопрос как решённый